# How to call Obj-c initializer class method with no params from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a class in Obj-C, it can only be initialized by calling `+new`, and `-init` is not supported:

```
@interface SetupMainController : UIViewController
+(SetupMainController *)new;
-(id)init __attribute__((unavailable("Must use +new")));
@end
```

I am trying to run the following equivalent obj-c code in swift:

```
SetupMainController *setupController = [SetupMainController new];
[self presentViewController:setupController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

like so:

```
let sc : SparkSetupMainController = SparkSetupMainController.new()
```

or:

```
let sc : SparkSetupMainController.new()
```

or:

```
let sc : SparkSetupMainController()
```

(which obviously tries to call -init which is prohibited)
all fails, 
getting "expected member name following '.'" error.

I found answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452604/how-to-call-a-factory-method-of-an-objective-c-class-from-swift) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093693/create-swift-instance-from-objective-c-factory-method) or [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_26) but none give a straight answer how to do that simple task in Swift.

Help appriciated

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Calling new is jus calling alloc init. There doesn't seem to be a reason to make init unavailable.

Comment: because implementation of +new()  is doing this:
`return [[SetupMainController getSetupStoryboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"root"];`
function `getSetupStoryboard` is a class method as well, loading the relevant storyboard from the bundle

Comment: You should not have that in new. You should have a method called something like `setupViewControllerFromStoryboard`.

Comment: ok, let's say the class method is called `setupViewControllerFromStoryboard()`, how do I call that from swift?

Comment: Like you call any class method. `Class.methodName()`.

Comment: so problem is the reserved name `new`?

Comment: Yes I think so. I was surprised that you were able to use new at all. Normally Xcode will shout at you for using a method name beginning with new.

Comment: strange. it worked in Obj-C without issues

Comment: There are some strange behaviours like that. I had a problem with a property name of `message`. It didn't have warnings but caused bugs that were only fixed by changing the name.

Comment: Solved: use back ticks, like `let string = NSString.`new`()`. Look my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `new`in your Objective-C class to:

```
+(id)mynew;
```

Then suddenly all works:

```
    var s: SetupMainController = SetupMainController.mynew()
```

Don't know why you cannot override `+new`. Maybe it's because is a class method?

**EDIT**: To add more mystery to this question, if you look up `new` in Apple's doc is defined in Swift using:

```
class func `new`() -> Self!
```

Do the backticks mean something like "this is reserved"?

**EDIT 2**: Looks like `new` doesn't work at all with Swift

This code does not compile:

```
let j = NSNumber.new()
var s = NSString.new()
```

**EDIT 3:**: SOLUTION

new is a reserved keyword in Swift, so to call `+new()` you need to add the back ticks:

```
let string = NSString.`new`()
```

Kudos to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29511313/225503)

Comment: lovely! didn't know that about the backticks, nor that new is reserved.
decided to resolve to using normal -init() in the `SetupMainController` Obj-c class
my question, is this ok to do?
`-(instancetype)init
{
    return [[SetupMainController getSetupStoryboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"root"];

}` (not calling [super init] at any point)

Comment: Yes, but looks a little fragile: you depend on having a VC with a "root" identifier. Better create two inits, one initWithIdentifier: that gets an NSString and one init that call the designated initWithIdentifier passing "root"

Comment: thing is I do not want to expose initWithIdentifier to user since this viewController must be instantiated only from the "root" storyboard instance, otherwise return nil. (so cannot mark it as NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER anyways)