# Why using new() class method to create an object in Swift doesn't compile?

Tags: swift, initialization

I wasn't a big fan of `new` in Objective-C. But [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29507127/225503) raised the doubt. Why this does not compile?:

```
let j = NSNumber.new()
var s = NSString.new()
```

Looks like `new()` is a regular class method. Although in Apple's doc is defined with back ticks around the name ??

```
class func `new`() -> Self!
```

So, the question remains. If `new()` is there in NSObject, why does not compile? File Radar?

Comment: It *does* compile with Xcode 6.3 beta 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new` is a reserved keyword and you have to escape it with backticks. This will work:

```
let string = NSString.`new`()
```

But I recommend using the "Swift" way as it shorter, cleaner and works for non `NSObject` kinds:

```
let string = NSString()
```