# UUID in Swift iOS 8.1

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem when i try to change my App to iOS 8.1. The Syntax to create a UUID doesent work anymore:

```
var uuid = NSUUID.UUID().UUIDString
```

How to create a uuid in iOS 8.1 with Swift?

Comment: Have a look at the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214061/how-are-objective-c-factory-methods-converted-into-swift-convenience-initializer Swift while converting Objective-C looks for class factory methods and maps them to Swift initializers. This is why `[NSUUID UUID]` is mapped to `NSUUID()` instead of `NSUUID.UUID()` thus `NSUUID.UUID().UUIDString` does not work (I'm not sure why it used to work though).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Swift 3:

```
var uuid = NSUUID().uuidString
print("UUID string: \(uuid)") // UUID string: D7C7F26B-608A-465A-ADF8-4F5365513E5D
```

> Swift 2:

```
var uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString
println("UUID string: \(uuid)") // UUID string: 76A4073A-D79C-45FD-A5D6-86E52AD8C771
```

Comment: Thank you - that worked (ill checked out the autocomplete from NSUUID(), but there is no UUIDString (maybe a Bug))

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 3 you can do the following:

```
UUID().uuidString
```