# Swift class in Objective-C project (Compiler error)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I created an Swift class in my Objective-C project. There are no problems with the generated bridging interfaces between objective-c and swift.

In my objective-c project, I have an class named `Task`, its `Task.h` looks like following:

```
@interface Task: NSObject
…
- (id) initWithHomeworks:(NSDictionary *)homeworks
@end
```

The **Task.m** looks like this:

```
@implementation Task

- (id) initWithHomeworks:(NSDictionary *)settings {
    self = [super init];
    //Do something with self...
    ...
    return self
 }
```

My swift code inherits the above class:

```
import Foundation

class SubTask : Task {
   //Compiler Error 1 
   func initWithHomeworks(homeworks: Dictionary<String, String>) -> AnyObject{ 
      //Compiler Error 2
      return super.initWithSettings(settings)
  }
}
```

I get two compiler errors in the place commented above. The error messages are below:

Compiler Error 1:

```
Method ‘initWithHomeworks’ with Objective-C selector ‘initWithHomeworks:’ conflicts with initializer ‘init(homework:)’ from superclass ‘Task’ with the same Objective-C selector
```

(I haven't declared any method `init(homework:)`)

Compiler Error 2:

```
‘Task’ does not have a member named ‘initWithHomeworks’
```

Why I get these two errors in my Swift class? How to fix them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental reason for that you are seeing is that Swift converts Objective-C methods names intelligently. [From the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html):

> To instantiate an Objective-C class in Swift, you call one of its
>   initializers with Swift syntax. When Objective-C init methods come
>   over to Swift, they take on native Swift initializer syntax. The
>   “init” prefix gets sliced off and becomes a keyword to indicate that
>   the method is an initializer. For init methods that begin with
>   “initWith,” the “With” also gets sliced off. The first letter of the
>   selector piece that had “init” or “initWith” split off from it becomes
>   lowercase, and that selector piece is treated as the name of the first
>   argument. The rest of the selector pieces also correspond to argument
>   names. Each selector piece goes inside the parentheses and is required
>   at the call site.

In your case the Objective-C `initWithHomeworks:(NSDictionary *)homeworks` method is converted to Swift as `init(homeworks: [NSObject : AnyObject]!)`. You can override it as follows:

Given an Objective-C header:

```
@interface Task : NSObject

- (id)initWithHomeworks:(NSDictionary *)homeworks;

@end
```

Swift subclass:

```
class SubTask : Task {

    override init!(homeworks: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
        super.init(homeworks: homeworks)
    }

}
```

This answer was completed using Swift 1.2 in Xcode 6.4

**Update based on comments**

You have defined your SubTask's initialiser as a regular function:

```
func initWithHomeworks(homeworks: Dictionary<String, String>) -> AnyObject{ 
    return super.initWithSettings(settings)
}
```

This is incorrect for the following reasons:-

1. `func` is not allowed on init methods
2. init methods shouldn't declare a return type, remove `-> AnyObject`
3. init methods don't return anything, remove the `return` keyword from the super.init...

Swift initialisers [do not return a value](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) however you can still assign the result to a variable:

Swift:

```
var mySubTask = SubTask(homeworks: someDictionary)
```

Objective-C:

```
SubTask *mySubTask = [[SubTask alloc] initWithHomeworks:someDictionary];
```

Comment: It *is* clearly documented. See "Initialization" in https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html: *" Swift syntax. When Objective-C init methods come over to Swift, they take on native Swift initializer syntax. The “init” prefix gets sliced off  ... etc etc"* – See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214061/how-are-objective-c-factory-methods-converted-into-swift-convenience-initializer.

Comment: In objective-c `- (id)initWithHomeworks:(NSDictionary *)homeworks;` , the  return type is `id` which means any object, in swift version, it doesn't indicate return type with `AnyObject` ,why? I am asking this because in another class, it calls this initializer and instantiate an object with the returned object. That is also indicated in my question where I have the code `return super.initWithSettings(settings)`

Comment: The init method in Swift does not indicate the return type because ["Swift initializers do not return a value"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html). Maybe the other class is a regular function that returns an object.

Comment: Please check my update about Task.m, I need the return, since in objective-c code, the other class call this initWithHomeworks & assign the returned value to a variable. My swift class need the same return, so that the other class could also call initWithHomeworks in my swift class and return an object to assign to a variable. How to do that?

Comment: I see your update based on comment about `var mySubTask = SubTask(homeworks: someDictionary)`. But I need to call the swift class from objective-c code, get the returned object and assign to an variable. I mean this step is in objetive C code, not swift code. Do you know how to do it then?

Comment: See my latest update, that includes a sample of how you would call the Swift init from Objective-C

Comment: Hi , thanks very much, I will give a try later, if everything works, I will upvote & accept your answer for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override init method,you should write it like this

```
class SubTask:Task{
    override init!(homeworks: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
        super.init(homeworks: homeworks)
    }
}
```